# How to redirect page after login in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to reactjs and trying to redirect the page after a user registers. Here is my App.js, which has a register input.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


 function App() {
  const [registerUsername, setRegisterUsername] = useState("");
  const [registerPassword, setRegisterPassword] = useState("");
  const [registerPasswordAgain, setRegisterPasswordAgain] = useState("");
  const [registerEmail, setRegisterEmail] = useState("");
  const register = () => {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      data: {
        registerUsername,
        registerPassword,
        registerPasswordAgain,
        registerEmail
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      url: "http://localhost:4000/register"
    }).then((res) => console.log(res));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
    
    <div class = "topnav">
        <a class="active" href="/register.html">Register </a>
        <a class="active" href="/play.html">Play</a>
        
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <input placeholder ="Enter your username" onChange={e => setRegisterUsername(e.target.value)} />
        <input type="password" placeholder ="Enter your password" onChange={e => setRegisterPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <input type="password" placeholder ="Enter your password again" onChange={e => setRegisterPasswordAgain(e.target.value)} />
        <input placeholder ="Enter your email" onChange={e => setRegisterEmail(e.target.value)} />
        <button onClick={register}>Submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

this sends the registration username/password to my backend which is written in node.js. Assuming I send back a 200 OK status, or something that indicates that the user has registered, how can I redirect this page to another, lets say a login page? Do I need to create a class that extends component?

Just wondering where to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: So you're not using a router in your App? We use react router to do the redirect once the users are authenticated

Answer (score 0):

use [React-Router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start)

and in react we don't use  anchor tag  because react is SPA (Single page application), so use LINK tag

simple Example

index.js

```
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-route-dom'
<React.StrictMode>
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>,
```

app.js

```
import {Switch,Rout,Link} from 'React-router-dom'
<div>
     <Switch>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users">  {/add your redirect path/}
        <Users />            {/Users components will render after the URL changes } 
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" exact>
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
    
    <Link to="/user">
      <button>
            Login
      </button>
    </Link>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `react-router-dome` `Redirect` component you can redirect your page to abother page.

in your case you can store a boolean state and make it true when user suucessfully logged in.

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
....
const [logged,setLogged] = useState(false)
.....
 url: "http://localhost:4000/register"
    }).then((res) => if(res.Sucess){
   setLogged(true)
};
```

in your main component. you can add a redirect component like.

```
    <div className="App">
{logged && <Redirect to="redirect-url" />}
```

Comment: Thanks - When you say main component do you mean my app.js? And should the first snippet of code you put be done in my app.js too?

Comment: not the main App.js file, i mean component in which you need to redirect.in your case it is app .